# How to create and start an Akka stream inside a stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an akka stream that processes some messages. When an event occurs the stream should create a new instance of a different akka stream.

At the moment this is what I am doing. Is this the best way?

```
if(event.happened) new AnalysisFlow(info.id,info.time).flow
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @Neysofu Ok great, thanks. I dont know what I thought their would be another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If `event` is part of the stream, you might be able to use [`groupBy`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.4/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L1198) to split your stream into substreams.

You can also use [`flatMapConcat`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.4/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L1372) or [`flatMapMerge`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.4/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L1387) to transform your stream of elements to stream of `Source`s which then are run and flattened in using concat or merge strategy correspondingly.